# JIRA/confluence alternative

Tags: project-management, jira, confluence

Please tell me what kind of programs you use insted of JIRA/confluence. I don't like jira because the design is so Java style. For example I like the PivotalTracker for tracking fresh projects.

What do you suggest? THX!

Comment: Do you like MS Project (TFS)?

Comment: What do you mean by "because the design is so Java style"?

Comment: Java style is "not for designers" because the UI is bad.

Comment: UI bad? wait until you see BugZilla :)

Comment: That is why I don't use BugZilla :).

Comment: I was forced to use PivotalTracker at a consultancy. The app made no sense to me at all. I am a Java developer, so that probably explains it ;-)

Answer (score 14):

[Phabricator](http://phabricator.org/) is a suite of web applications that help software companies communicate about software effectively. It was created at Facebook. 
Didn't try it yet, but looks like a good option.

Comment: We use Phabricator at work - the performance is blazing, it has awesome code review, tight integration with git, task management, projects (grouping tasks with priority) and lots more besides. I highly recommend it.

Comment: Wow.  That looks pretty nice.  Can't believe I haven't heard of it before!

Answer (score 9):

For **Project Management**, [Trello](https://trello.com/tour) is a sweet free alternative, albeit with much fewer features.

For **sharing files** with the team, [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/) is a good option (the shared folders feature is awesome).

For **VCS+more**, you can use something simple like Github, or more powerful tools like [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine) or [Kiln](http://www.fogcreek.com/kiln/).

---

A quick search on Google gets you more quasi-interesting projects:

- [FogBugz](http://www.fogcreek.com/fogbugz/) (Fog Creek software, again)
- [Gemini](http://www.geminiplatform.com/)
- [Squish](http://www.squishlist.com/about/why.html)
- [Bontq](http://www.bontq.com/)
- [Elementool](http://www.elementool.com/)
- [YouTRACK](https://www.jetbrains.com/youtrack/) (from the lovely chaps who make InteliJ IDEA)
- [Lighthouse](http://lighthouseapp.com/)
- [The Bug Genie](http://www.thebuggenie.com/)

Answer (score 4):

personally i like http://leankitkanban.com for my project/ task tracking and i use http://pbworks.com for my wiki at work

i think its complete personal taste though

Answer (score 2):

[Redmine](http://www.redmine.org) is a good alternative. It combines wiki and issue tracker pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [CounterSoft Gemini](http://countersoft.com) works for you?

Comment: Nope. I hate Gemini myself.

Answer (score 1):

Mindtouch is really great. They have a community version, and their scripting is very intuitive. Searching is fast, and their user community is really lively.

Answer (score 1):

Try with Fusion Forge is nice http://www.fusionforge.org/ works for me..

Answer (score 1):

A lot of projects in our company use Trac (see [The Trac Project](http://trac.edgewall.org/)). It is a combination of a lightweight wiki, issue tracker and integrator for Subversion commits. Written in Python, there are some plugins available for it, so it may expanded pretty easy. I like JIRA and Confluence more, but that is a personal preference.